# Shebang, interpreter and a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

One can use `shebang` line to provide the interpreter to use to execute a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
```

My question is how can we determine in the script which interpreter is indeed used. The following doesn't work:

```
echo $0
echo $SHELL
```

Comment: If the script is being executed, the shebang applies, so unless I have not-Bash under `/bin/bash`, it's Bash. If the script is being interpreted (sourced) then you cannot always tell because any code that checks against it needs to be valid to the interpreter; and I can use any interpreter, even the most insane one. Compare: [*How to detect if a script is being sourced*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2683279).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Nope; the shebang is often overridden by running a script with e.g. `sh scriptname` -- this ignores the shebang and runs the script with whichever "sh" is first in `$PATH` (and even if that's bash, it runs with some bash extensions disabled).

Comment: @Gordon I execute a script like `./scriptname`, the file must be executable, `ps -e` shows `scriptname`. I interpret a script by `sh scriptname`, the file may not be executable, `ps -e` shows `sh`. How I name these two ways is irrelevant. My main point was: it's impossible to tell the interpreter from within interpreted script, unless you are prepared for this particular interpreter. Show me a script that detects `bash` when run with `bash`, detects `python` when run with `python` and detects `bazbaz` when run with `bazbaz` (an interpreter you know nothing about). The whole idea is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to extract the shell from the first line of the script.

When you use `$SHELL` you are showing the shell you are actually using, which need not be the same as that specified on the first line: for instance, you can use use the `.`/`source` command to run any script in whatever shell is currently running.

The following will show the shell from the first line:

```
sed -n '1 s/^#!//p' "$0"
```

Here `$0` is the running script, and the `sed` command prints the first line with the leading `#!` removed. If there is no such line, then nothing will be returned, and you can check for this.

You can use `$(...)` to get the value from the `sed` command, eg:-

```
echo Script "$0" is running with "$SHELL"
echo It should run with "$(sed -n '1 s/^#!//p' "$0")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
echo $(readlink -e /proc/$$/exe)
```

(in other words, check the executable for your own process).

Edit: It seems `$SHELL` isn't reliable. Put this in a `idshell` file:

```
echo I am process $$
echo SHELL is $SHELL
echo /proc/$$/exe is $(readlink -e /proc/$$/exe)
```

and then compare the outputs of:

```
>bash idshell
I am process 24012
SHELL is /bin/bash
/proc/24012/exe is /bin/bash
```

and

```
>dash idshell
I am process 24062
SHELL is /bin/bash
/proc/24062/exe is /bin/dash
```

So, `dash` is lying??? (and so is `sh` since it resolves to `dash` on my Ubuntu).

Comment: Isn't this a useless use of `echo`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - It is, in the literal example, but it seems to be meant to suggest other uses, such as assigning to a variable or making a string comparison.

Comment: Is this any different from `echo "$SHELL"`?

Comment: @kamil `echo 'Just an example...' | cat`  :)

Comment: @AFH `$SHELL` doesn't seem to be reliable enough, see my edited answer.

Comment: @xenoid - Interesting. I was asking, because I didn't know. I need to investigate the relationship between `/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable`, `/bin/dash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object` and `/bin/sh:   symbolic link to dash` (Ubuntu `file` reports). I've not noticed _shared objects_ before. And this leaves the question even more open: what shell information does the questioner want?